# Inno setup intercept enter key on pages

Tags: inno-setup, enter, pascalscript

May be this is a stupid question but I'm not able to intercept the Enter key in my Inno setup pages. :-(

I'm able to intercept other keys using

```
WizardForm.OnKeyPress:=@MyFormKeyPress
```

or

```
WizardForm.OnKeyDown:=@MyFormKeyDown
```

into the InitializeWizard() and setting the `WizardForm.KeyPreview` property to True also.

But... what about the Enter key? It seems it's handled by Inno before the OnKeyPress/OnKeyDown events, so, for example, the NextButtonClick() is always executed before.

To be more clear, what I wish to do is to use only the mouse (not the Enter key) to switch from a page to another by clicking on the "Next" button.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: It is the `NextButton.Default` property set to True, which "eats" the key. However, what you're going to do will be probably hard, because even if you turn off `TabStop` the user will still be able to focus the button with a mouse click. And there's more that this.

Comment: I thought that installing OnKeyPress/OnKeyDown event functions the WizardForm was able to catch ALL the keyboard keys BEFORE anything else (like in Delphi...or I'm wrong?). Instead, the ONLY not intercepted keyboard key seems to be the VK_RETURN (enter) key... and this is very strange...